# Challenges with Card Validation and Database Interaction in Stripe Payment Implementation

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, stripe-payments, radzen

**Stripe Integration in Radzen Blazor**

Clicking the "Pay Now" button without entering any card details prompts a validation message to appear.
[Stripe Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtsNT.png)

I've implemented a script for the Pay Now button, which is triggered within the CreateShoppingCartObject method.

This script includes the creation of a Payment Intent method for Stripe Payments. My goal is to validate the card information before it's submitted.

razor.cs page

[ShoppingCartInvoke C# Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4J7S.png)

[Payment Intent Response C# Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgIhd.png)

However, I'm encountering an issue with the validation process in the invokeMethod.

It seems that the validation isn't being recognized, and it doesn't access whether a card number has been entered.

As a result, the data is directly stored in the database without undergoing the necessary validation checks.

.razor page
[Razor Html Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTMg9.png)

I attempted to address this by trying to detect validation using JavaScript.

Unfortunately, the script generates its own iframe, limiting access to the validation process.

Consequently, I'm unable to verify the card information before the Pay Now button is activated.

[Bind Card Js Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p42ON.png)

[Payment Submit Event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTOZb.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the help center, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see what and [How to Ask]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 0):

What kind of validation are you talking about? I don't see your frontend code collecting card details, and you hard coded a test payment method in your backend end.

Comment: Clicking the "Pay Now" button without entering any card details prompts a validation message to appear. 
I have attached a UI image to my question

Comment: Please don't post comments or questions as answers